# Error in R while creating a 3d scatter plot

Tags: r

I entered a code for the 3d scatter plot and got the following error:

`Error in xyz.coords(x = x, y = y, z = z, xlab = xlabel, ylab = ylabel, : 'x', 'y' and 'z' lengths differ`

The code entered was as follows:

```
x <- rbinom(1000, 8, 0.5) y <- rbinom(1000, 8, 0.5) K <- c(rep(0:8,times = 9), rep(0:8, each = 9)) k <- matrix(k, ncol=2, byrow = FALSE) z <- k[,1]+k[,2] cdf <- rep(0.0, times = 81) for (i in 1:81) {cdf[i] <- sum(x+y <= z[i])/1000}

scatterplot3d(k[,1], k[,2], cdf, highlight.3d = TRUE, col.axis ="blue", main="Plotting Bivariate CDF", pch = 20, ylab = "Values of y", xlab = "Values of x", zlab = "CDF of x+y")
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this error - I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Correct your line `matrix(K, ncol=2, byrow = FALSE) ` with `K` not `k`

Comment: thanks a ton.....its working....